# How do I parse a date as an argument with argparse?

Tags: python, date, command-line, argparse

Im trying to write a python program that I will run at the command line. I'd like the program to take a single input variable. Specifically, I would use a date in the form of 2014-01-28 (yyyy-mm-dd):

e.g. `python my_script.py 2014-01-28`

It seems argparse might be able to help me but I have found very little documentation regarding the module. Does anyone have experience with something like this?

Answer (score 127):

There's lots of documentation [in the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html), but generally, something like:

```py
import argparse
import datetime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
        'date',
        type=lambda s: datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d'),
)

# For testing.  Pass no arguments in production
args = parser.parse_args(['2012-01-12'])
print(args.date) # prints datetime.datetime object
```

Comment: basically i could replace args with sys.argv[1]?

Comment: @ChaseCB -- If you pass a list to `parse_args`, it will be used as if those arguments were passed on the command line.  Under normal circumstances (if you don't pass anything) `argparse` uses `sys.argv[1:]`.  See http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.parse_args

Comment: `parser.parse_args('this is a test string'.split())` is another test option.  It's equivalent to `parse_args(['this','is',...])`, and in a few edge conditions better.

Comment: @hpaulj -- better?  I can't think of any way that it's better unless your argument is "it saves you some typing"...

Comment: I must have been mis-remembering how `choices` are best defined.  The real reason I favor `split` is it can save typing.  `shlex.split` would be a better choice if I wanted to simulate how the shell creates `sys.argv`

Comment: One way in which `split` is more like `sys.argv` is in string identity. `['test','string'][0] is 'test'` is `True`.  `'test string'.split()[0] is 'test'` is `False`.  Fortunately `argparse` only uses the `is` test once, and it probably shouldn't do so even there.  http://bugs.python.org/issue18943

Comment: That's strangely interesting... Thanks for pointing that out (although I still don't think I'll be writing my tests with `str.split` ;-)

Answer (score 105):

As of Python 3.7, a (marginally) more convenient option is `fromisoformat`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.fromisoformat

Using it, you can replace the relevant line in mgilson's code with this:

`parser.add_argument('date', type=datetime.date.fromisoformat)`

(I would also add a `help` argument to this invocation of `add_argument`, and mention that the input should be in ISO format.)

Comment: To get both date and time use `parser.add_argument('date', type=datetime.datetime.fromisoformat, help='ISOformat - YYYY-MM-DD:HH:mm:ss')`