# How to define argparse default argument choices and "wildcard", dynamic choice that needs be verified to be accepted?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm currently building a command line interface in Python 3 with the `argparse` module.

I have a situation where I need to define choices (e.g. `"today", "yesterday", "week"`, ...) for an optional `argparse` argument `-s` of a subparser, but also allow a date string, but only if it can be successfully parsed as `datetime.datetime` with a predefined format (e.g. "%Y-%m-%d"), otherwise an exception would be `raise`d.

```py
parser.add_argument(
            "-s",
            "--start-date",
            type=str,
            default="today",
            choices=["today", "yesterday", "week", <date>],  # date should be accepted only if datetime.strptime(date, "%Y-%m-%d") is successful
            help="start date help",
        )
```

Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21437258/how-do-i-parse-a-date-as-an-argument-with-argparse ?

Comment: @AlexandruPlacinta Only to a degree, because I also need to offer "today", "yesterday", etc. as options, which aren't datetime.datetimes yet, but strings that will be later interpreted as such.

Comment: The idea is the same, though, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/25470943/3001761 - you have a custom type function that takes a string and either returns a value or rejects the input by throwing an error. You'd do the interpreting as such here, so the rest of the program just deals with datetimes.

Comment: While  use of a custom `type` function here is great, don't be afraid to accept a simple string, and do the testing/conversion after parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my previous question, I believe this will suffice you, the custom function that validates your input. If it is the base case with **today, yesterday, week**, you return the strung, otherwise you try to parse the date object.

You can change it however you see fit, but this illustrates your need.

```
import argparse

def parse_date(s):
    if s.lower() in ["today", "yesterday", "week"]:
        return s
    
    return datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%Y-%m-%d")

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument(
            "-s",
            "--start-date",
            type=lambda s: parse_date(s),
            default="today",
            help="start date help",
        )
```